# Mongoose "Options not supported"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have all these 'not supported' options error when I use yarn start.  The project utilizes MERN stack.   Based on my google research I'm pretty sure it has to do with the Mongoose setting options, but I don't know where to look or next steps to figure the problem out.

Error page:

[image: img]

```
Here is my server.js
```

```
//Bring in Depedencies
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const routes = require("./routes");
    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

    //Define middleware
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    //Serve up static assets on heroku
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
        app.use(express.static("client/build"));
    }
    //Add routes, both API and view
    app.use(routes);

    //Connect to the Mongo DB
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/hotsheetmedical", { useNewUrlParser: true });


    //Start the API Server
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log(`  ==> API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT}!`);
    })
```

As far as my package.json.  It may be because of that, as I have two package.json.  One was created when I cloned the git repository.  The other was created with create-react-app.  I was instructed to do that, but pretty sure that's causing problems...or will if it isn't already.

Here is the package.json which is on the main level with my server.js

```
    {
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "express-router": "^0.0.1",
        "if-env": "^1.0.4",
        "mongod": "^2.0.0",
        "mongoose": "^5.4.0",
        "react": "^16.7.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
        "react-router": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "reactstrap": "^6.5.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js"
      },
      "name": "hotsheetmedical",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "server.js",
      "devDependencies": {},
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "description": ""
    }
```

Here is the package.json that was created with Create-react-app and is in the client folder

```
    {
      "name": "hotsheetmedical",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.6.3",
        "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
        "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
      ]
    }
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can post that would be helpful.  And also thanks for guiding me. I'm sure it's a silly newbie mistake, that I just can't see.

Comment: would help if you actually post your package.json and code on server.js

Comment: Please show us your mongoose initialization code. and your app.js/server.js

Comment: Could you try removing `{ useNewUrlParser: true }` option while connection to your db ?

Comment: @RajKumar I tried that, but it still came up with the same error.

Comment: I tried your code with same mongoose version and `MongoDB shell version v4.0.3`
which version of mongodb are you using ?

Comment: @RajKumar I have Mongoose 5.4 and I don't use MongoDB Shell, I was taught to use Studio 3T.  Though I need to install compass as I only have a trial of Studio 3T which is almost over.